# How do I copy and modify LayoutParams to set them on a programmatically created widget?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams, android-layoutparams

My goal is to programmatically create and add TextView widgets to a ConstraintLayout, positioned at different angles around a circle relative to another widget, ie using the circular layout constraint.

In my activity.xml I add a TextView `txtCentred` centred in the layout, and a TextView `txtPositioned` positioned relative to this using the circular constraint.

At runtime, I then add new TextView widgets to the view. For each new widget I make a copy of `txtPositioned.LayoutParams`, modify the circleAngle field of the copy, and set the copy on the new TextView

The result I get is that all TextViews are positioned in the same place, as if they are being positioned using the last `LayoutParams` I created. They are also all sized using the size of the last TextView I added. It seems like even though the LayoutParams are separate copies, they all link to some single object behind the scenes.

One thing I noticed is that all the different LayoutParams objects's "ConstraintWidget" has the same hashcode. But maybe this is just the txtCentred widget?

***Screenshot of app running in the emulator, showing all widgets positioned in the same location:***

[image]

The manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCentred"
            android:text="X"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPositioned"
            android:text="R"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/txtCentred"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="10"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The activity class

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Add a TextView, circular positioning
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun AddTextView(text: String, atAngle: Float, parent: ConstraintLayout, layoutParamsSource: TextView):TextView {
        var newWidget = TextView(this)
        parent.addView(newWidget)
        newWidget.setTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large)
        var layoutParamsCopy =
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParamsSource.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
        layoutParamsCopy.circleAngle = atAngle
        newWidget.layoutParams = layoutParamsCopy
        newWidget.setText(text)
        newWidget.scaleX = 5.0F
        newWidget.scaleY = 5.0F
        return newWidget
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var parentLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.parentLayout) as ConstraintLayout
        var txtPositioned = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtPositioned) as TextView;

        // add 4 TextViews in cardinal directions relative to txtCentred
        var o = AddTextView("O", 0.0F, parentLayout, txtPositioned)
        o.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#80ff0000"))
        var k = AddTextView("K", 90.0F, parentLayout, txtPositioned)
        k.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8000ff00"))
        k.scaleX = 5.0F
        var a = AddTextView("A", 180.0F, parentLayout, txtPositioned)
        a.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800000ff"))
        a.scaleX = 5.0F
        var y = AddTextView("Y", 270.0F, parentLayout, txtPositioned)
        y.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#80ff8000"))
        y.scaleX = 5.0F


        Log.d("d", "o=${(o.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).circleAngle}")
        Log.d("d", "k=${(k.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).circleAngle}")
        Log.d("d", "a=${(a.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).circleAngle}")
        Log.d("d", "y=${(y.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).circleAngle}")
    }
}
```

**LogCat debug output showing different circleAngle values for each widget:**

```
2021-07-10 15:16:10.569 29143-29143/com.example.myapplication D/d: o=0.0
2021-07-10 15:16:10.569 29143-29143/com.example.myapplication D/d: k=90.0
2021-07-10 15:16:10.569 29143-29143/com.example.myapplication D/d: a=180.0
2021-07-10 15:16:10.569 29143-29143/com.example.myapplication D/d: y=270.0
```

Comment: I ended up creating a new LayoutParams with the width/height constructor (passing `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for these parameters). This worked.